# Why can I not pass props to child component React?

Tags: reactjs

Here is the Parent code. I currently have code for the date to update and pass to a date component, but now working on a stopwatch and having trouble passing the props into the stopwatch child component. The counter will continue to count but the new number submitted does not update or pass to the stopwatch component.

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        deadline: 'December 25, 2018',
        newDeadline: '',
        counter: 75,
        newCounter: ''
    };
}

changeDeadline() {
    this.setState({deadline: this.state.newDeadline});
}

changeNumber() {
    this.setState({counter: this.state.newCounter});
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className='App'>
            <div className='App-title'>Countdown to {this.state.deadline}</div>
            <Clock 
                deadline={this.state.deadline}
            />
            <Form inline>
                <FormControl
                    className="Deadline-input"
                    placeholder='New Date'
                    onChange={event => this.setState({newDeadline: event.target.value})}
                />
                <Button onClick={() => this.changeDeadline()}>Submit</Button>
            </Form>

            <div>Stopwatch From { this.state.counter } Seconds</div>
            <Stopwatch 
                counter={this.state.counter}
            />

            <Form inline>
                <FormControl
                    className="Deadline-input"
                    placeholder='New Number'
                    onChange={event => this.setState({newCounter: event.target.value})}
                />
                <Button onClick={() => this.changeNumber()}>Submit</Button>
            </Form>

        </div>
    )

}
```

}

Here is the Stopwatch code;

```
class Stopwatch extends Component {
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {currentCount: this.props.counter}
}

timer() {
this.setState({
  currentCount: this.state.currentCount - 1
})
if(this.state.currentCount < 1) { 
  clearInterval(this.intervalId);
}
}
componentDidMount() {
this.intervalId = setInterval(this.timer.bind(this), 1000);
}
componentWillUnmount(){
  clearInterval(this.intervalId);
}
render() {
  return(
  <div>{this.state.currentCount}</div>
);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

in the child constructor, you are referencing `this.props`, but this is not binded to the component there, so you are actually setting undefined.

You need to use `props.counter` and it will work.

Comment: on the parent side the counter is set to 75 which when you originally run the app it starts to count down from 75, but when you change the number and submit on the parent side the child does not update.

Comment: @Acer79 your problem seems to be that you are directly assingning this.state in the child. you should always use `this.setState` to update your state, otherwise react has no way of knowing it needs to updates a particular part of your UI

Answer (score 0):

@acer79, can you use the following code for the `App.js`:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      counter: 75,
      newCounter: 75
    };
    this.setInputNumber = this.setInputNumber.bind(this);
  }

  setInputNumber(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({counter: Number(event.target.value)})
  }

  changeNumber() {
    this.setState({newCounter: this.state.counter});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <div>Stopwatch From { this.state.newCounter || this.state.counter} Seconds</div>
        <Stopwatch
          counter={this.state.newCounter}
        />
        <Form inline>
          <FormControl
            className="Deadline-input"
            placeholder='New Number'
            onChange={this.setInputNumber}
          />
          <Button onClick={() => this.changeNumber()}>Submit</Button>
        </Form>

      </div>
    )

  }
}
```

and the following for the `Stopwatch.js`:

```
import React from 'react';


export default class Stopwatch extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {currentCount: props.counter}
  }

  timer() {
    this.setState({
      currentCount: this.state.currentCount - 1
    })
    if (this.state.currentCount < 1) {
      clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(this.timer.bind(this), 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    debugger;
    if(nextProps.counter !== this.props.counter){
      this.state = {currentCount: nextProps.counter}
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.state.currentCount}</div>
    );
  }
}
```